# Global variable not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been beating my head against the wall with this.  Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
var foo = 100;

function loadData() {
   // this pops up a window that says it's 100
   alert(foo);  

   $.getJSON(myvars.constants.ajaxpath + "getsettings", function(data) {
      foo = 200;
      // this pops up a window that says it's 200
      alert(foo);
   });
   // this pops up a window that says it's 100
   alert(foo); 
}
```

Any value that I set the global variable to inside the getJSON() call is only valid within the getJSON() call.  Once the function exits the global variable reverts back to its previous value.

How can I set this global variable from within the getJSON() call?  I've tried using .success(), .complete(), etc. as well.  I want it to stay set to 200, not revert to 100.

Thanks!

P.S.  Obviously I'm doing other things with global variables in the getJSON() call, but the simple variable settings are to illustrate the issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your...

```
foo = 200
```

... is being called once the ajax request returns. So this is AFTER the "last" `alert(foo)`.
Once execution of this script has completed, if you pop open your developer console (F12) and type in `foo`, you should see 200.

Comment: As a side note - I would say set this to be `async: false` - but that is deprecated in jQuery, so you should't do that :)

Answer (score 1):

The variable is *not* being set back, the third and final `alert` is simply called before the set.

Because you're using an asynchronous JSON call, execution will not be linear. In most cases, that code will go something like:

```
var foo = 100;

function loadData() {
   // this pops up a window that says it's 100
   alert(foo);  

   // The call is sent at this point
   $.getJSON(myvars.constants.ajaxpath + "getsettings");

   // this pops up a window that says it's 100
   alert(foo); 
}

// Some time later, after the server responds, this function is actually run

function(data) {
   foo = 200;
   // this pops up a window that says it's 200
   alert(foo);
});
```

You can test this simply by either calling alert or displaying `foo` after the call returns, or setting the JSON call to be synchronous, which will force execution to flow as you expect (but is very poor practice).

Answer (score 0):

Here you set callback on success event, and this callback will be called when ajax request will be successfully completed.

```
$.getJSON(myvars.constants.ajaxpath + "getsettings", function(data) {
  foo = 200;
  alert(foo);
});
```

Last line where you alert foo is executed earlier. So after ajax reqest you variable will be 200.

Comment: Thank you, everybody.  I get it now.  

I knew this already, but in the process of trying to debug something else I let myself get fooled and forget that this was normal behavior.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var foo = 100;

function loadData() {

   alert(foo);  
   $.ajax({
      async: false,
      url: myvars.constants.ajaxpath + "getsettings",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
      foo = 200;
      alert(foo);
   }
 });
  alert(foo); 
}
```